# Sequence animation using CAAnimationGroup

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-animation

I'm trying to make a sequence of animations, I've found in `CAAnimationGroup` the right class to achieve that object. In practice I'm adding on a view different subviews and I'd like to animate their entry with a bounce effect, the fact is that I want to see their animations happening right after the previous has finished. I know that I can set the delegate, but I thought that the `CAAnimationGroup` was the right choice. 
Later I discovered that the group animation can belong only to one layer, but I need it on different layers on screen. Of course on the hosting layer doesn't work.
Some suggestions?

```
- (void) didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
    float startTime = 0;
    NSMutableArray * animArray = @[].mutableCopy;
    for (int i = 1; i<=_score; i++) {
        NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self.greenLeaf];
        UIImageView * greenLeafImageView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: archivedData];
        greenLeafImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenLeaf"];
        CGPoint leafCenter =  calculatePointCoordinateWithRadiusAndRotation(63, -(M_PI/11 * i) - M_PI_2);
        greenLeafImageView.center = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(leafCenter, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height));
        [self addSubview:greenLeafImageView];

        //Animation creation
        CAKeyframeAnimation *bounceAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
        greenLeafImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        bounceAnimation.values = @[
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]
                                  ];

        bounceAnimation.duration = 2;
        bounceAnimation.beginTime = startTime;
        startTime += bounceAnimation.duration;

        [animArray addObject:bounceAnimation];
        //[greenLeafImageView.layer addAnimation:bounceAnimation forKey:nil];


    }
    // Rotation animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/11 * _score);
    }];
    CAAnimationGroup * group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    group.animations = animArray;
    group.duration = [[ animArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.duration"] floatValue];
    [self.layer addAnimation:group forKey:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`CAAnimationGroup` is meant for having multiple `CAAnimation` subclasses being stacked together to form an animation, for instance, one animation can perform an scale, the other moves it around, while a third one can rotate it, it's not meant for managing multiple layers, but for having multiple overlaying animations.

That said, I think the easiest way to solve your issue, is to assign each `CAAnimation` a `beginTime` equivalent to the sum of the durations of all the previous ones, to illustrate:

```
for i in 0 ..< 20
{
    let view : UIView = // Obtain/create the view...;
    let bounce = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

    bounce.duration  = 0.5;
    bounce.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + bounce.duration * CFTimeInterval(i);

    // ...

    view.layer.addAnimation(bounce, forKey:"anim.bounce")
}
```

Notice that everyone gets `duration * i`, and the `CACurrentMediaTime()` is a necessity when using the `beginTime` property (it's basically a high-precision timestamp for "now", used in animations). The whole line could be interpreted as `now + duration * i`.

Must be noted, that if a `CAAnimation`s is added to a `CAAnimationGroup`, then its `beginTime` becomes relative to the group's begin time, so a value of `5.0` on an animation, would be `5.0` seconds after the whole group starts. In this case, you don't use the CACurrentMediaTime()

Answer (score 4):

If you review [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimationGroup_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), you will note that `CAAnimationGroup` inherits from `CAAnimation`, and that `CAAnimation` can only be assigned to one `CALayer`. It's intent is really to make it easy to create and manage multiple animations you wish to apply to a `CALayer` at the same time, not to manager animations for multiple `CALayer` objects.

To handle the sequencing of different animations between different `CALayer` or `UIView`objects, a technique I use is to create an `NSOperation` for each object/animation, then throw them into a `NSOperationQueue` to manage the sequencing. This is a bit complicated as you have to use the animation completion callback to tell the `NSOperation` it is finished, but if you write a good animation management subclass of `NSOperation`, it can be rather convenient and allow you to create sophisticated sequencing paths. The low-rent way of accomplishing the sequencing goal is to simply set the `beginTime` property on your `CAAnimation` object (which comes from it's adoption of the `CAMediaTiming` protocol) as appropriate to get the timing you want.

With that said, I am going to point you to some code that I wrote and open-sourced to solve the exact same use case you describe. You may find it [on github here](https://github.com/michaelkamprath/iPhoneMK/tree/master/Views/MKSoundCoordinatedAnimationView) (same code included). I will add the following notes:

- My animation management code allow your to define your animation in a plist by identifying the sequence and timing of image changes, scale changes, position changes, etc. It's actually pretty convenient and cleaner to adjust your animation in a plist file rather than in code (which is why I wrote this).
- If the user is not expected to interact with the subviews you creating, it's actually much better (less overhead) to create layer objects that are added as sub-layers to your hosting view's layer.

Comment: I will look into that it seems a really interesting approach