# How to add two CABasicAnimations on a single uiview's layer?

Tags: ios, core-animation, caanimation

I am adding animations to a uiview's layer, what happening is that when i add first animation it is going through, but adding a second animation removes the first one, how can i add two cabasicanimation parallely? Please help me how to do so.

[image]

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if (![ViewController weakDevice]) {
    _imageView_BlurBackground.image = _blurBackgroundImage;
}else{
    _imageView_BlurBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:96.0/255.0      green:96.0/255.0 blue:96.0/255.0 alpha:0.9];
}
CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];

// Mask image ends with 0.15 opacity on both sides. Set the background color of the layer
// to the same value so the layer can extend the mask image.
maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.40f] CGColor];
maskLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Mask3.png"] CGImage];


// Center the mask image on twice the width of the text layer, so it starts to the left
// of the text layer and moves to its right when we translate it by width.
maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;

maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, -_creditListView.frame.size.height, _creditListView.frame.size.width, _creditListView.frame.size.height*2);

// Animate the mask layer's horizontal position
CABasicAnimation *maskAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
maskAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_creditListView.frame.size.height];
maskAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];

maskAnim.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
maskAnim.duration = 6.0f;
[maskLayer addAnimation:maskAnim forKey:@"slideAnim"];
_creditListView.layer.mask = maskLayer;

[_scrollView_CreditList setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView_CreditList.frame.size.width,  _imageView_CreditList.frame.size.height+20)];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startRolling) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];}
```

Update:

the second downward flash of white highlight should start when the first one has reached about 80% of its downward motion, followed by subsequent flashes following the same pattern.

My view hierarchy is

```
CreditViewController--->
     View---->       
          BlurBackground UIView
          FirstAnimationView--->
                  ScrollView
                  ImageView
          SecondAnimationView--->
                  ScrollView
                  ImageView
```

Please provide me your suggestion, how should i implement this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764375/sequence-animation-using-caanimationgroup

Comment: "but adding a second animation removed the first one" are the two animations animating the same key path?

Comment: yes they use the same key path.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `CAAnimationGroup` to group all of the animations together, then apply just the animation group to the view.

Using this technique you can have multiple animations on different keypaths running concurrently and you can schedule multiple animation on the same keypath to run in sequence (by setting the appropriate timing details).

Note that you can not have multiple animations running on the same keypath at the same time using an animation group or any other approach.

Comment: I don't think it can solve my problem. because in the group also when second animation will start, the first one will stop. But i need that both animations work together.

Comment: actually i have an animation that is rolling down using position.y ketPath and i want that when first animation has completed 90% of the screen height another animation pops from the top without affecting the first one, which is not happening. when i add second animation using same keyPath first animation is erased.

Comment: Answer updated, you need to change your idea about what you want... It sounds kind of like you should be applying the animations to different views / layers

Comment: thanx, thats what i were thinking of. What should be the alternate to this?

Comment: You don't describe enough about what you're trying to animate and how your views / layers are composed to say. I don't know what you mean by `another animation pops from the top` - is that a second view going up as the first view completes moving down?

Comment: Question updated. I have added the image you can see an mask effect on "additional ...." in image. this effect is going down from the top so when it reaches to 90% of the text i want to add another effect from the top.

Comment: So the credits are animating down and the 'popover' window should animate up and off screen at the end? So the animations should be applied to different views

Comment: Please describe what views you have which make up the screenshot you show, and of those views, which are you applying the animations to

Comment: If i use two image views then i will need to synchronise the content offset of the two scroll views added on different view, and will need to track the animation status? How can i do this?