# continus animation with google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, animation

I have this method:

```
private func setupCameraPositionForMovement(markerPos: CLLocationCoordinate2D, secondPos: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    let bearing = bearingBetweenLatLngs(markerPos, end: secondPos)
    let cameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition(target: markerPos, zoom: 16, bearing: bearing + 20, viewingAngle: 90)

    map.animateToCameraPosition(cameraPosition)
}
```

I am using this method to animate movement from `markerPos` to `secondPos`, And this work fine when I call it once like:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1)
setupCameraPositionForMovement(markers[selectedIndex - 1].position, secondPos: markers[selectedIndex].position)
CATransaction.commit()
```

Now, I want to call this animation multiple times to display a continues movement,
So I tried this code:

```
for i in 1..<markers.count {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1)
    setupCameraPositionForMovement(markers[i - 1].position, secondPos: markers[i].position)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

But without any benefit.

When I searched for this problem I found something like `CAAnimationGroup`, But I did not know how to use it in this situation.

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAAnimationGroup allows multiple animations to be grouped and run concurrently. The grouped animations run in the time space specified by the CAAnimationGroup instance.

The duration of the grouped animations are not scaled to the duration of their CAAnimationGroup. Instead, the animations are clipped to the duration of the animation group.

CAAnimationGroup has only one property: animations.

This property is intended to add an array of animations to a layer. Suppose, for example, you want to change the transparency of a layer while your are moving it on the screen. If you simply create the two animations and add them to a layer one by one, you loose the control of the synchronization and depending on what your app is doing, you could have some visible delay between the 2 animations.

For more information check this [page](https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/core-animation-part-iv-grouping-animations/).

You can also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764375/sequence-animation-using-caanimationgroup) for more information.

Comment: So, how I can make continues movement in my case ?